# fitting of non-overlapping squares into a rectangle

Tags: geometry

You are given 2 Squares such that sum of their area is 1. You want to fit these 2 Squares inside a Rectangle, without overlaping, such that sides of the Rectangle are parallel to the sides of the Squares. Find the area of smallest such Rectangle for which we can always fit the 2 Squares.

Comment: I assume this is a homework question, so I'm only going to give you a hint.

Try drawing a picture of how the rectangle will have to look. Consider what happens if the two square are equal size; or if one is larger than the other.

Comment: I have tried but i am getting answer as sqrt(2) and it is not correct. This is a mathematician erdos question by the way and not a homework question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as its author admits *This is a mathematician erdos question*.  It is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: how can it be an off topic question its related to geometry and geometry is under mathematics.!

Comment: [so] is about programming, not [math.se]. See the [help/on-topic] for details. Thank you.

Comment: can u suggest me a famous mathematics website like this so that i can post it there!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a trap, I don't see it.

Let the sides of the smallest and largest squares be `sin(t)` and `cos(t)`, with `0<t<π/4`.

The short side of the rectangle must be `Max(max(sin(t), cos(t)))=Max(cos(t))`, i.e. `1`, and the long side `Max(sin(t)+cos(t))=√2`. Hence the area `√2`.

---

If the question is about the maxmin area of a rectangle (the largest area of the tight bounding boxes), the solution is given by `Max(cos(t)(sin(t)+cos(t)))`, i.e. `cos(π/8)(sin(π/8)+cos(π/8))`.